# Backbone.js collection call XML file using this.fetch ERROR

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, backbone.js, fetch

```
myBook = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    initialize: function(models, geturl) {
        var self = this;
        this.url = geturl;
        this.fetch({
            dataType: "xml",
            async: false,
            success: function(collection, xml) {
                ...
                ...
                ...
            }
        });
    }
});
```

I can't get this to work. Anyone please advise me to solve this problem. I really need to call an XML from the collection. I tried using $.ajax() but failed, so i try using backbone.js function to fetch the XML, but unfortunately i can't get it to work.

Im using:-
    Backbone.js 0.9.2 & 
    jQuery v1.8.3

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Backbone expects the server response as JSON. You should override [`Model.parse`](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-parse) with a function that parses the XML and returns a plain Javascript object. [`jQuery.parseXML`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/) is pretty handy for mapping simple XML to an object.

Assuming your XML response would look like this:

```
<root>
  <id>1</id>
  <foo bar="foobar">foo</foo>
</root>
```

And you wanted the model properties to look like:

```
{
  id:1,
  foo:'foo',
  foobar:'foobar'
}
```

You could parse it as follows:

```
var YourModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
  parse: function(xml) {
    var $xml = $.parseXML(xml);
    return {
      id:      parseInt($xml.find('id').text(), 10),
      foo:     $xml.find('foo').text(),
      foobar:  $xml.find('foo').attr('bar')
    }
  }  
});
```